# compare between two images with face recognition using tflite_flutter but have issue in code

Tags: android, flutter, dart, tflite

user will take a selfie and i will compare this photo with the back-end photo
so i have two images
i want to verify if the same person or not
i'm using **tflite_flutter 0.9.1** and installed install.bat
this is the function i get from **chatGPT-4**

```
Future<bool> compareImages(String imagePath1, String imagePath2) async {
final inputImage1 = InputImage.fromFilePath(imagePath1);
final inputImage2 = InputImage.fromFilePath(imagePath2);

final faceDetector = GoogleMlKit.vision.faceDetector();
final faces1 = await faceDetector.processImage(inputImage1);
final faces2 = await faceDetector.processImage(inputImage2);

if (faces1.isEmpty || faces2.isEmpty) {
  return false;
}

// Load the TFLite model
const modelPath = 'mobilefacenet.tflite';
// final modelFile = File(modelPath);
final model =
  await Interpreter.fromAsset(modelPath, options: InterpreterOptions());

// Define input and output shapes
final inputShape = model.getInputTensor(0).shape;
final outputShape = model.getOutputTensor(0).shape;

// Prepare input tensors
final input1 = _prepareInputTensor(inputImage1, inputShape);
final input2 = _prepareInputTensor(inputImage2, inputShape);

// Run inference
final output1 = List.filled(outputShape[1], 0.0).reshape([1, outputShape[1]]);
final output2 = List.filled(outputShape[1], 0.0).reshape([1, outputShape[1]]);
dev.log("outputShape $outputShape");
dev.log("output1 $output1");
dev.log("output2 $output2");
model.run(input1, output1);
model.run(input2, output2);

// Compute the distance between the embeddings
final distance = _euclideanDistance(output1[0], output2[0]);

return distance < 0.6;
}

Float32List _prepareInputTensor(InputImage inputImage, List<int> inputShape) {
// Pre-process the input image according to the model's requirements
// For example: resize, normalize, etc.
final inputData = Float32List(
  inputShape[0] * inputShape[1] * inputShape[2] * inputShape[3]);
// Fill `inputData` with pre-processed image data
return inputData;
}

double _euclideanDistance(List<double> a, List<double> b) {
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
double diff = a[i] - b[i];
sum += diff * diff;
}
return sqrt(sum);
}
```

**#this is the terminal output**

```
[log] outputShape [1, 192]

E/tflite  (28254): tensorflow/lite/kernels/conv.cc:346 input->dims->size != 4 (1 != 4)

E/tflite  (28254): Node number 0 (CONV_2D) failed to prepare.

E/flutter (28254): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Bad 
state: failed precondition

E/flutter (28254): #0      checkState

check.dart:74
E/flutter (28254): #1      Interpreter.allocateTensors

interpreter.dart:142
E/flutter (28254): #2      Interpreter.runForMultipleInputs

interpreter.dart:180
E/flutter (28254): #3      Interpreter.run
interpreter.dart:157
E/flutter (28254): #4      compareImages

face_detection_helper.dart:40

E/flutter (28254): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (28254): #5      _ISignSignOutScreenState.getCurrentView.<anonymous closure>

ISignSignOutScreen.dart:493

E/flutter (28254): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (28254): #6      _CustomButtonState.build.<anonymous closure>

CustomButton.dart:84

E/flutter (28254): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (28254):

[log] output1 [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

[log] output2 [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

also i'm wondering why all output is zeros
**how to fix it**

Answer (score 0):

**this is chatGPT-4 answer**
It seems that the issue is related to the input tensor dimensions. The error message suggests that the input tensor should have 4 dimensions, but it only has 1. To resolve this issue, you should check the dimensions of the input tensor and reshape it to have the required dimensions. Before you call runForMultipleInputs or run, make sure to preprocess the input images properly. The input tensor should have a shape of [1, height, width, channels], where height and width are the dimensions of the input images and channels are the number of color channels (usually 3 for RGB images)

You can reshape an input tensor using the reshape function. Here's an example of how to preprocess the input images before passing them to the TFLite model:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';

// Load the image file and decode it
img.Image image1 = img.decodeImage(await File('path/to/image1.jpg').readAsBytes());
img.Image image2 = img.decodeImage(await File('path/to/image2.jpg').readAsBytes());

// Resize the images to the dimensions expected by the model (e.g., 128x128)
img.Image resizedImage1 = img.copyResize(image1, height: 128, width: 128);
img.Image resizedImage2 = img.copyResize(image2, height: 128, width: 128);

// Convert the images to Float32List format
Float32List input1 = imageToFloat32List(resizedImage1);
Float32List input2 = imageToFloat32List(resizedImage2);

// Run the model
interpreter.runForMultipleInputs([input1, input2], output);

// Helper function to convert an image to a Float32List
Float32List imageToFloat32List(img.Image image) {
  var convertedBytes = Float32List(1 * image.width * image.height * 3);
  var buffer = Float32List.view(convertedBytes.buffer);
  int pixelIndex = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < image.height; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < image.width; j++) {
      int pixel = image.getPixel(j, i);
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getRed(pixel)) / 255.0;
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getGreen(pixel)) / 255.0;
      buffer[pixelIndex++] = (img.getBlue(pixel)) / 255.0;
    }
  }
  return convertedBytes;
}
```

Make sure to adjust the dimensions (e.g., 128x128) according to the input size expected by your model. This should resolve the issue, and you should be able to run the TFLite model without errors.